# Stored Procedure to get the count using 2 tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a complicated stored procedure for the first time. My goal is to get the count with some condition from 2 tables.

Consider Merchant table and Email table.
Email table saves the Email invitations sent by the Merchant. Merchant table has all the Merchant Info along with Email IDs. 
My goal is to get the count of EmailID s that are in the Merchant table by checking if the Email invitations sent by Merchant has signed up.

I have tried to make this question clear... Hope i am clear.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What database are you using? And what does the procedure do with these counts it calculates? Do you want a stored function instead which would return them to the caller?

Comment: @RedFilter: There is no schema with me. I am just learning :(

Comment: sql 2005 is the platform. It will just display the count that these many merchants have signed up after the invitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why a stored procedure? It sounds like it can be done in a single SQL query.

Let's see if I understand your question correctly: Merchants invite other people to become a Merchant as well and you want a list with the number of accepted invitations per merchant?

Something along those lines:

```
select MerchantName, count(1)
from Merchants, Emails
where Merchants.Id = Emails.Id
and Emails.SignedUp = 'YES!'
group by MerchantName;
```

Comment: Awesome Martin!! You are just amazing :)

Comment: Sure, especially the part where he has count(1) in the query

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is some confusion in that schema you're describing. Based on what I think you're trying to do I'd suggest you have a Merchant table, an Email table and a MerchantEmail table which links Merchants to email invitations sent.

The way it appears otherwise with a Merchant table that has an Email ID is a many-to-one relationship so that several Merchants could be the recipients of an email. In that case the Signed Up flag would appear in the Merchants table and not in the Email table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMerchantsSignedUp
@EmailId INT
AS
SELECT COUNT(*) AS MerchantSignedUp
FROM Merchant, Email
WHERE Merchant.EmailId = Email.Id
AND Merchant.SignedUp = 1
AND Email.Id = @EmailId
```

- Please note that there is some redundancy above which suggests that you need not even include the Email table in the query. Here it acts only to indicate a foreign key relationship.